# Error building C program

Tags: c, xcode

Here are my 2 source files:

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "part2.c"

extern int var1;
extern int array1[];

int main()
{
    var1 = 4;
    array1[0] = 2;
    array1[1] = 4;
    array1[2] = 5;
    array1[3] = 7;

    display();

    printf("---------------");

    printf("Var1: %d", var1);
    printf("array elements:");

    int x;
    for(x = 0;x < 4;++x)
        printf("%d: %d", x, array1[x]);

    return 0;
}
```

**part2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var1;
int array1[4];

void display(void);

void display(void)
{
    printf("Var1: %d", var1);
    printf("array elements:");

    int x;
    for(x = 0;x < 4;++x)
        printf("%d: %d", x, array1[x]);
}
```

When i try to compile the program this is what i get:

> Ld /Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-blxrdmnozbbrbwhcekmouessaprf/Build/Products/Debug/Test normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/John/Xcode/Test
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -L/Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-blxrdmnozbbrbwhcekmouessaprf/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-blxrdmnozbbrbwhcekmouessaprf/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-blxrdmnozbbrbwhcekmouessaprf/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -o /Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-blxrdmnozbbrbwhcekmouessaprf/Build/Products/Debug/Test
>
> ld: **duplicate symbol _display** in /Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-blxrdmnozbbrbwhcekmouessaprf/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/part2.o and /Users/John/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-blxrdmnozbbrbwhcekmouessaprf/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using Xcode and both files are inside of a C project called `Test`

What is causing the error and how do i fix it?

Comment: First, learn how to use [header files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file).

Comment: I've bolded the only part of the error message that is probably relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove "`#include "part2.c"`" and change it to "`#include "part2.h`"

And move your function declaration of:

```
void display(void);
```

from the top of your "`part.c`" file into a file named "`part2.h`", which should be included  in (or put at the top of) both .c files.

Comment: And make sure to pass into both .c files to the compiler.

Comment: In general, you really shouldn't be including `.c` files -- just `#include foo.h` and then link with the `.c`.